# Is there exist a system call in Ubuntu Linux which could make subthread directly read main thread's cmd parameter?

Tags: linux, pthreads, system-calls

Recently i'm doing my parallel programming exercise, which made me curious to the question of parameter sending. As we all know we could use function pthread_create to create a subthread which could execute function where pthread_create's parameter mentioned, as the parameter sending does, but if i want to sending more parameter, i have to define a global structual body. Its quite complex as i wonder, if there have a system call could quickly passing those parameter directly to the subthread?

Comment: threads share the same address space so no system call is required. read about work queues

Comment: Short answer - no.

Answer (score 0):

Within the pthreads API, there is only one way to start a new thread: by calling `pthread_create()`.  The caller has one `void *` parameter available for use to convey information to the new thread, and this is sufficient for arbitrary data, though threads can access external and in-scope static variables, too, of course.

If you want to send data more complex than a single array to the new thread via `pthread_create`'s fourth parameter then yes, you need to do so in the form of a structure object of a type known both to the thread function and to the caller of `pthread_create`.  I suppose it's in the eye of the beholder how complex that is.  In any case, no, there is no other way within pthreads.

In practice, it is uncommon in real-world programs that a structure type serves *only* the purpose of conveying initialization data to new threads, and that tends to moot the complexity question.

Answer (score 0):

The arguments passed to main function can be passed to the thread function, too.
And no, there are system calls to do that.

It's not as complicated as you might think.

A simple program that does it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct cmd_args
{
    int argc;
    char **argv;
};

void *thread_func(void *t)
{
    struct cmd_args *args = t;

    for (int i = 1; i < args->argc; ++i)
        printf(" arg[%d] = %s\n", i, args->argv[i]);

    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct cmd_args args = {.argc = argc, .argv = argv };

    pthread_t tid;
    pthread_create(&tid, NULL, thread_func, &args);

    pthread_join(tid, NULL);
}
```

This is based on two premises.

1. Your thread function doesn't modify the `argv` (in case multiple threads exist and they all want to modify)
2. The main thread waits for the thread function to complete before exiting

If that's not suitable, you could simply make a copy of the argv and pass it to threads. For example, you could do the following to make a copy
like the following for each of the thread:

(left out error checking for brevity)

```
struct cmd_args *p = malloc(sizeof *p);
p->argc = argc;
p->argv = malloc(argc * sizeof(char*));
for (int i = 0; i < argc; ++i)
    p->argv[i] = strdup(argv[i]);
```

And let the threads handle the `free`ing of these allocations:

```
struct cmd_args *p = t;

...

for (int i = 0; i < argc; ++i)
    free(p->argv[i]);

free(p->argv);
free(p);
```